# Open Jupyter Notebook with Open Data Cube in docker

Tags: docker, open-data-cube

I run open data cube (ODC) docker (opendatacube-core and jupyterhub) and I expected that I can run jupyter notebook into it with ODC. However, I didn't. How can I run container (docker) of ODC and I can use Jupyter notebook with ODC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an example configuration of the Open Data Cube and Docker available called "[Cube in a Box](https://github.com/opendatacube/cube-in-a-box)".

You should be able to get something up using just Docker Compose, as shown below, but the above repository has an example of a Dockerfile, Docker Compose configuration and product definition and indexing scripts.

```
version: '3'

services:
postgres:
    image: postgres:10.3
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_DB=opendatacube
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=opendatacubepassword
    - POSTGRES_USER=opendatacube

jupyter:
    image: opendatacube/jupyter
    environment:
    - DB_HOSTNAME=postgres
    - DB_USERNAME=opendatacube
    - DB_PASSWORD=opendatacubepassword
    - DB_DATABASE=opendatacube
    ports:
    - "80:8888"
    volumes:
    - ./notebooks:/notebooks
    command: jupyter notebook --allow-root --ip="0.0.0.0" --NotebookApp.token='secretpassword'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think that with it I can taste ODC a lot. Very good!

Comment: I need to put ports: - "8888:8888" to work here.

Comment: The one I showed will make Jupyter accessible on port `80`. Up to you what you do there!

Comment: Very good. You make me happy today! Good!